# How to get data in AutoCompleteTextView using mySQL and Json?

Tags: android, mysql, json

i tried with this code
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public String data;
    public List<String> suggest;
    public AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
        autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String newText = s.toString();
                new getJson().execute(newText);
            }

        });

    }
    class getJson extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... key) {
            String newText = key[0];
            newText = newText.trim();
            newText = newText.replace(" ", "+");
            try{
                HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/autocmplt/abc.php?name=");
                ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                data = hClient.execute(hGet,rHandler);
                suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.getJSONArray(1).length();i++){
                    String SuggestKey = jArray.getJSONArray(1).getString(i);
                    suggest.add(SuggestKey);
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item,suggest);
                    autoComplete.setAdapter(aAdapter);
                    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

this is my main_activity.xml
here i create autocompletetextview

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="13"
        android:hint="AutoCompleteTextView" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my item.xml file
here i used TextView for dropdown menu.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:background="#eaeaea">
</TextView>
```

response of .php file

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","name":"sachin"},{"id":"2","name":"solanki"},{"id":"3","name":"abc"},{"id":"4","name":"abcd"}]}
```

This is how i am trying..

getting error like

```
08-17 18:14:33.745 5284-5307/com.example.sachin.autocomplete W/Error: Value {"results":[{"id":"1","name":"sachin"},{"id":"2","name":"solanki"},{"id":"3","name":"abc"},{"id":"4","name":"abcd"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are parsing your JSON correctly?  Unless the returned string you posted is not correct, I get an exception with your code trying to parse it.  I'd suggest using a json framework with POJOs instead:

The first test fails below, the second succeeds:

```
@Test
    public void testJson() {

        String data = "{\"results\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"sachin\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"solanki\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"abc\"},{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"abcd\"}]}";
        JSONArray jArray = null;
        ArrayList<String> suggest = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.getJSONArray(1).length();i++){
                String SuggestKey = jArray.getJSONArray(1).getString(i);
                suggest.add(SuggestKey);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testJson2() {

        String data = "{\"results\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"sachin\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"solanki\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"abc\"},{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"abcd\"}]}";
        ArrayList<String> suggest = new ArrayList<>();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Results r = gson.fromJson(data, Results.class);
        for ( Custom c : r.customArray ) {
            suggest.add(c.name);
        }
    }

    class Results {
        @SerializedName("results")
        @Expose
        public ArrayList<Custom> customArray;
    }

    class Custom {
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        public String id;
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        public String name;
    }
```

Comment: i am sorry sir bt i didnt getting this point..and this is my first project so little confused about this thing..

Comment: These are simple unit tests for testing isolated sections of code.  The first unit test is your code that throws an exception while parsing the json string.  The second test is my proposed solution to your code that fails.